# I need my code to display the users name, their GPA, and then a credit which is their GPA times 10

Tags: java

I need my code to display the users name, their GPA, and then a credit which is their GPA times 10. The code below is what I have so far but every time I run the program the output is just, "EEEEEEEEEE EEEEEE....". Can you guys please tell me what I can do to fix this? All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BookstoreCredit {

public static void main (String args[])
{
    String name;
    double gpa;
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print ("Please enter your name >>> ");
    name = inputDevice.nextLine();
    System.out.print ("Please enter your grade point average >>> ");
    gpa = inputDevice.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.print (name);
    System.out.print (", your GPA is ");   
    System.out.print (gpa);
    System.out.print (", so your credit is $");
    
}

public static void computeDiscount(String name, double gpa)
{
        double credit;
        credit = gpa * 10.0;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think your code compiles, the way it's written here.  So if you're running a class file somehow, it will be from an older version of your code.  The first thing you need to do is fix the compile errors - start by moving `return credit;` down one line from where you have it now, and change `void` to `double` in the method header.

Comment: When you've sorted that out, your next issue will be that your `main` method doesn't actually call your `computeDiscount` method anywhere.  You'll need to add the line `computeDiscount(name,gpa);` into your `main` method somewhere.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thank you. I have moved the 'return credit;' line down and the 'System.out.print (credit);' down as well. I have also added the line 'computeDiscount(name,gpa);' to the main method as you suggested and changed the 'void' to 'double' in the method header. The top portion of the code worked but when I added my public static void computeDiscount method it started displaying only E's. Thanks again for your input though. I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.  I suspect your teacher probably wanted printing the credit to happen in the `main` method, not the `computeDiscount` method, but that is the next issue for you to sort out.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, the teacher did ask that of us and while I have made all of the edits to my code that you suggested I am still getting a result of E's. Thank you for your help though. I'm going to keep playing around with the code to see if I can make it work.

Comment: There is no earthly reason why your code would print all Es, other than that you're actually running some other class.  There is nothing in your code here that prints Es.  Just make sure that whatever you add, there are no compile errors.  These will usually be shown in your IDE with some kind of visual indicator, such as a red wavy line.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem. I had to refresh my browser. I guess it was a glitch in the system. I now have rewritten some of the code and can still get the main method to work fine but I just can figure out how to call my second method to display in main but I'm getting closer! Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like Hollis has done your homework for you.  I hope you've  still managed to learn something from the exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking something like this?:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookstoreCredit {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name;
        double gpa;
        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter your name >>> ");
        name = inputDevice.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter your grade point average >>> ");
        gpa = inputDevice.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(name);
        System.out.print(", your GPA is ");
        System.out.print(gpa);
        System.out.print(", so your credit is " + computeDiscount(gpa));

    }

    public static double computeDiscount(double gpa) {
        double credit;
        credit = gpa * 10.0;
        return credit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I actually managed to get it to work but my call statement looks different than what you have. I like being able to compare how they are written differently yet do the same thing. Lets me know that there's more than one way to look at programming!